# Mixing HTML and Razor Code Within Nested Conditionals

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to use Razor withh a few nested conditionals, which is by far the most complex intermingling of Razor and HTML I have attempted thus far and I admit that I am not an expert with Razor yet. I am getting Razor parsing errors of this type: "Only assignment,call,decrement,increment, etc, can be used as a statement..."

Seems like I am using too many "@" but if I remove it here @<td> I get more errors that a statement is expected and symbol "td" cannot be resolved. I thought Razor was smart enough to know when HTML was being presented in a code block? I am clearly not giving Razor what it needs.

The first parse error occurs at `"@<td rowspan="@total">N/A</td>;"`

```
@foreach (var customerId in customerIds)
{
    var attendance = records.Where(x => customerIds.Contains(x.Customer.CustomerId)).ToList();
    var total = attendance.Count();

    if (total > 0)
    {
        <tr>
            @{
                var i = 0;
                attendance.ForEach(x =>
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {

                        @<td rowspan="@total">@x.Customer.CustomerFullName</td>;
                        @<td rowspan="@total">N/A</td>;

                    }

                    @<td>@x.Event.EventTitle</td>;
                    @<td>@x.AttendanceStartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy")</td>;
                    @<td style="width: 10%; text-align: center">
         }
    }
 }
 }
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You do not need to put `@` and `;` before/after DOM element in your Razor block (i.e. `@{ }` ).
  Here a good [link](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29#BM_CombiningTextMarkupAndCode) to understand how to combine Text, Markup, and Code in Code Blocks
- To loop on each item in `attendance` you need to use a `for` loop (or a `foreach` loop if you don't need to increment a counter).
- The closing tag for the last TD element is missing.

You can try this :

```
foreach (var customerId in customerIds)
{
    var attendance = records.Where(x => customerIds.Contains(x.Customer.CustomerId)).ToList();
    var total = attendance.Count();

    if (total > 0)
    {
        <tr>
            @for (var i = 0; i < total; i++)
            {
                var x = attendance[i];
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    <td rowspan="@total">@x.Customer.CustomerFullName</td>
                    <td rowspan="@total">N/A</td>
                }
                <td>@x.Event.EventTitle</td>
                <td>@x.AttendanceStartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy")</td>
                <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center"></td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need the @ symbol when you are using .NET stuff; HTML shouldn't have the @ symbol.  Remove it from all of the `<td>` tags.

This implies a .NET block:

```
@{
   int x = 1;
   x++;
   @: This (@:) breaks out of .NET and says that this text is plain HTML
   x--; //back to .NET
}
```

Also, you're not closing your table row tag, that might throw some of the extra errors you are seeing.

```
if (total > 0)
        {
            <tr>
                @{
                    var i = 0;
                    attendance.ForEach(x =>
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {

                            <td rowspan="@total">@x.Customer.CustomerFullName</td>;
                            <td rowspan="@total">N/A</td>;

                        }

                        <td>@x.Event.EventTitle</td>;
                        <td>@x.AttendanceStartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy")</td>;
                        <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center">
             }
        }
```

EDIT: Whoa, also, the attendance.ForEach() is trying to modify each element of attendance object; it doesn't iterate through each Element.  I think you want another foreach loop instead of calling Object.ForEach().

Comment: Thanks. Per my description above I did mention that removing the @<td> causes a parser error

Comment: I can assure you that removing the @ is not what's throwing the error.  It's because you're trying to apply a transformation to the items in `attendance`.  I use Razor/HTML on a daily basis at my job, the syntax @<htmlTag> is not correct.  Change attendance.ForEach() into a foreach loop, remove the @ signs from the html tags and that code should work.